# Are there any examples in any of JRR Tolkien's writings where one can see through the eyes or take control of another being?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

I know the palantír can be used to see afar or communicate with other palantíri, but is there a device, character, or magical ability that allows one character to possess the consciousness and/or body of another being?

Comment: There's the connexion and control in the One Ring itself (Think: Gandalf protecting Frodo from The Eye on Amon Hen). There's Saruman's control over Théoden (poss. Gríma via poison?). Also the concept of ósanwë (telepathy), although that's more about connecting than controlling consciousness...

Comment: Yes, but it's nothing of the sort. I don't see why OP is asking that. Even if something like this would be possible in Middle-earth, Tolkien wouldn't mention it.

Comment: There are no examples, but writing an answer as such seems quite difficult. The only examples seem to be the persuasive nature of Annatar, and Grima's influence over Théoden.

Comment: Possession of another ensouled being seems like the kind of thing that Tolkien might have found inconsistent with his religious and philosophical beliefs about free will.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of no full possession of a living creature. The closest I can think of, aside from (as  mentioned in the comments above) the One Ring's influence over its bearer and Saruman and Grima's influence on Theoden (and similarly, Sauron's apparent poisoning of Denethor's thoughts):

- Sauron had strong influence over the bearers of the nine rings of Men (more subtle at first, but ultimately turning them into the Nazgûl), and some corrupting influence through the seven Dwarf rings.
- The Barrow Wights could take control of interred remains, and apparently cause paralysis among the living.
- Dragons like Glaurung could hypnotize people.
- In general, Maiar Saruman and Sauron (as Annatar) had the power to beguile with words.
- The Vala Irmo apparently had some sort of power over dreams.

Comment: Saruman's voice also had a hypnotic effect on listeners, before Gandalf brought him down.

Comment: @LAK - Yes, true.

Comment: @LAK - Thanks, I've added more about him.

Answer (score 2):

There's no example that exactly matches your description. A couple of somewhat similar examples:

- First it should be noted that the scene in the LotR movie where Saruman takes control over Théoden and sees through the King's eyes isn't canon, nor is the scene where Gandalf and Saurman is fighting over the control of Théoden.

  It the books, some manner of power was used to make Théoden complacent, weak and aged, but it seemed that he was mostly affected by Wormtongue's manipulations more so than something supernatural.
- Similar to the above, Sauron manages to break Denethor's will by communicating with him through the palantír. He doesn't directly control Denethor, but breaks his will and causes him to despair and turn mad.
- There is one example where the Sindarin Princess Lúthien uses some form of magic to let her and Beren take full possession of two dead, defeated beasts of Morgoth: a monstrous bat (*Thuringwethil*) and and a wolf (*Draugluin*).

  The exact nature of the spell she used isn't described, only that the disguise was good enough to let them enter Angband itself. It could have been an illusion that made them simply look like the creatures, or it could be something that actually let them possess the dead bodies. Regardless, it is clear that the creatures were dead when the spell was cast.
- Another example is the dragon Glaurung using some manner of mind control to manipulate Túrin, paralyzing him and making him believe that there was a chance for him to save his family members, instead of saving the war prisoners taken from Nagothrond. But Glaurung doesn't control him directly. Glaurung also uses his hypnotic powers to make Nienor lose all memory of her previous life.

Answer (score 1):

### Not exactly the same thing, but Morgoth was able to corrupt the órë [=heart, inner mind] of Men, such that they could not distinguish between Morgoth's thoughts and their own.

In some c.1968 linguistic notes, Tolkien discusses the meaning and background behind the elvish word "órë", which appears in *The Lord of the Rings* appendices as the name of one of the tengwar letters, and is translated as "heart (inner mind)".

> *órë* in nontechnical language, glossed ‘heart, inner mind’, nearest equivalent of ‘heart’ in our application to *feelings*, or *emotions* (courage, fear, hope, pity, etc.) including baneful ones. But it is also used more vaguely of things arising in the mind or entering the mind (*sanar*) which the Eldar regarded as sometimes the result of deep reflection (often proceeding in sleep) and sometimes of actual messages or influences on the mind – from other minds, including the greater minds of the Valar and so *indirectly* from Eru.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - "Notes on Órë" - manuscript</sub>

Tolkien mentions that in the early first age (prior to when we meet them in *The Silmarillion*), Men fell and worshipped Morgoth as a God, which gave him access to their óre, allowing him to insert his own thoughts such that they would resembled their own inner thoughts.

> Men, they said, certainly possessed (or had possessed) *óre*; but owing to the “haste” spoken of above they paid little attention to it. And there was another reason more dark (connected the Elves thought with human “death”): **the órë of Men was open to evil counsel, and was not safe to trust.**
> The Eldar surmised that some disaster had befallen Men before they became acquainted with them, sufficient to damage or alter the conditions under which they lived, especially with regard to their “death” and their attitude towards it. But of this Men, even the Atani with whom they became closely associated, would never speak clearly. “There is a shadow behind us”, they would say, but would not explain what that meant.
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - "Notes on Órë" - typescript</sub>

> The “disaster” the Elves thus suspected was some rebellion against Eru taking [the] form of accepting Melkor as God. **One consequence of this was that** the *fëa* was [?impaired] and **Melkor had claim upon those who had rebelled against him** and sought the protection of Eru, and access to [? ?] *óre* which [?amazed ? ?] but were [?useless] and **only the wisest of Men could distinguish between [?his] evil promptings and the true *óre*.**
>
> > [editor:] Despite the difficulty of the end of this passage, enough is legible that its meaning seems clear: through their acceptance of him as God, Melkor gained access to the *órë* of Men, so that only the wisest of Men could distinguish between the uncorrupted counsel of the *órë* and the evil promptings of Melkor. Cf. the statement in the typescript text that “the *órë* of Men was open to evil counsel, and was not safe to trust”.
>
> <sub>*The Nature of Middle-earth* - "Notes on Órë" - manuscript</sub>